# Can a business which only loses money be a "money laundering" method?

Tags: money-laundering

Let's say a criminal opens a business (a restaurant) which only loses money, there are basically no customers at all or there are very few in a way which is certainly non profitable in a given time period (say, a tax year).

Can that be a "money laundering" method, somehow?

Comment: There is a joke/oversimplification/slander that with some kinds of business, if you do get a receipt they're laundering money, if you don't get a receipt they're cheating on tax, because they could not possibly turn a profit. But there are alternative explanations. First is that the owner and family members are exploiting themselves by effectively working at less than minimum wage. Or they expect that things *will* get better real soon now.

Comment: Google `site:fatf-gafi.org restaurant`.

Comment: @o.m. a wealthy foreigner could operate a money losing business for the primary purpose of an immigrant investor visa - effectively a way for rich people to buy their way in.

Answer (score 4):

### Sure

You run a restaurant employing relatives and cronies and you scrupulously pay them and their taxes. Say $500k. That is clean money.

You take some money from running the restaurant but not enough to cover costs. Say $200k. However, you declare that your revenues were actually $800k with the difference being $600k of dirty money which “customers” paid in cash. You pay your taxes on your $300k profit and now have nice clean legitimate money.

Now, what legitimate businesses typically do is *under*report their cash income to minimise taxes but a laundering front *over*reports and pays too much tax to clean the money. For every $1 of dirty money going in you only get 70c out (or whatever depending on local taxes) but that money is clean.

Comment: Indeed a restaurant or bar where people typically pay in cash is a classic venue for this sort of scheme. If I recall correctly, the main character in Westlake's *The Busy Body* was running such a "fake bar" at the start of the novel.